# Whenever I try to download an app, it keeps wanting to download it to my old Android phone

Tags: google-play-store, installation

I bought a used Coolpad, but like new. Whenever I try to download an app, be it an old one already installed on old phone or a new, never before loaded one, it keeps wanting to send data to old phone, an LG Admire. In the box, looking for device compatibility, only the old phones model number comes up.

Comment: Does the Coolpad have Google Play installed on it?

Comment: From where are you trying to download the app?

Comment: thanks for responding. I hope I'm doing this right, and this is where I'm supposed to respond to you. Yes, Goggle play store is loaded on phone and it can be any app. from any where. smart tools, angry birds any one of of them. When looking for device compatability, it always comes up that it is but always it's the admire. I'm clueless, Thanks again, there are still a few good people out there.

Answer (score 0):

It is about Google Account I think. Logout and create a new account.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do a factory reset, then log on as yourself and try again.  There should then be no trace of any other accounts on that device and you should be able to start afresh.